# Arrays.sort for 2-D Integer Array failing

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm using the below method to sort a 2D Integer array. But there seems to be some issue with the sorting. Can someone please help.

```
private static Integer[][] sort(Integer[][] bs) {

    Arrays.sort(bs, new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer[] int1, Integer[] int2) {
            Integer numOfKeys1 = int1[1];
            Integer numOfKeys2 = int2[1];
            return numOfKeys1.compareTo(numOfKeys2);
        }
    });

    return bs;
  }
```

Input Array:

480 615
 
1320 1395 
1020 1140 
420 585 
540 780 
960 1065 
720 810 
690 750

Output:

420 585
 
480 615
 
690 750
 
**540 780**   - not sorted 
720 810
 
960 1065
 
1020 1140
 
1320 1395

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sorting by the second value not the first. 
Try something like:

```
Integer numOfKeys1 = int1[0];
Integer numOfKeys2 = int2[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

It actually IS sorted, but the key is the second record in your array. To sort it by the first node, you need to change your comparator to

```
public int compare(Integer[] int1, Integer[] int2) {
    Integer numOfKeys1 = int1[0];
    Integer numOfKeys2 = int2[0];
    return numOfKeys1.compareTo(numOfKeys2);
}
```

Or better write a comparator that sorts lexicographically

```
public int compare(Integer[] int1, Integer[] int2) {            
    int minlen = Math.min(int1.length, int2.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < minlen; ++i) {
        int cmp = int1[i].compareTo(int2[i]);
        if (cmp != 0) {
            return cmp;
        }
    }
    // so far the arrays are same, the shorter goes first
    return int1.length - int2.length;
}
```